# Migrating from a single dropdown list spinner to a dependant spinner using mySQL data

Tags: java, mysql, android-spinner

I have one spinner that populates with my SQL data. This works well. I now want to make it into a dependant spinner where the spinner I already have becomes the second or dependant spinner. I have added another spinner in my MainActivity.java. and it sucessfully retrieves the required mySQL data

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate spinner1 in activity_main.xml
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        // Spinner adapter
  List<String> typesofjobsunique = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(typesofjobs)); 
        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, typesofjobsunique));

        Collections.sort(typesofjobsunique);

        // Locate my spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlist));

        Collections.sort(worldlist);
```

What is the simplest coding approach to migrate from a single to a dependant spinner given the data retrieval itself works well for both spinners and I just want to make it dependant from the current independant format so

spinner1  typesofjobsunique only displays the
mySpinner worldlist 
spinner choices from mySQL corresponding to that particular typeofjobunique.

Most of the questions on here relating to dependant spinners, are where the data is in strings.xml which is not very helpful with remote data.

I'm assuming I will need to split my one adapter into two separate adapters, but I am unclear how to proceeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way that [Spinners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) work, if you want to implement dependence between them, you will need to use the current selection of one (spinner1) as the key for the list source of the other (mySpinner). You should implement an [AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) on spinner1 as recommended in the [Spinner guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener) and set the list in mySpinner. See code below:

```
// Locate spinner1 in activity_main.xml
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

// Locate mySpinner in activity_main.xml
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

// Spinner adapter
List<String> typesofjobsunique = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(typesofjobs)); 
spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, typesofjobsunique));

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // **EDIT**
        List<String> myWorldList = getWorldListForItem(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
        Collections.sort(myWorldList);
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        myWorldList));

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
});

Collections.sort(typesofjobsunique);
```

The implementation for getWorldListForItem() should query your database in the desired way. A hash table could also be used.

Hope that this is useful.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, the implementation for getWordListForItem() would look something like this:

```
List<String> getWordListForItem(String s) {
    String json = queryMySQLDatabase(s);
    List<String> results = parseJSONintoList(json);
    return results;
}
```

Also, the [AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(int pos)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) function returns a Java object of the type passed into the ArrayAdapter (which is a String in this case). Therefore getWordListForItem() takes a String argument.

As for the "Cannot resolve contructor ArrayAdaptor" error, please check the spelling (it's supposed to be ArrayAdapter not ArrayAdaptor). See [ArrayAdapter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) for more details... I've also fixed my implementation above to sort the list properly.

Comment: Having looked through my code I still cannot see where I should be implementing get WorldListFor Item()  so I am unable to get it to run in the same way as WorldList that worked previously.  I did amend mySpinner.setAdapter for getWorldListForItem, but the above code, stilI gives the message "Method call expected"  @j-beck

Comment: In order to get the dependence, you cannot independently query the data as you did before, there has to be some dependence in the data at some point. getWorldListForItem(Type t) takes the type associated with typesofjobsunique (I'm assuming String) and uses that to query the database. If this does not suit your database structure, you need to make the appropriate associations, i.e. there should be a world-list for each type-of-job.

Comment: Also, more info about the "Method call expected" error would be appreciated.

Comment: Each job_type used to populate spinner1 is associated with some corresponding job_title (s) in the mySQL database and is encoded in JSON. I am not sure how to query that data in a way that shows this association. My MainActivity.java shows one error at the getWorldListForItem line and is prompting me to Create method 'getWorldListForItem' However, my attempts to create this lead to the prompt Cannot resolve contructor 'ArrayAdaptor...'  @j-beck

Comment: Going to re-ask this as a seperate question about calling data from a dependant spinner, where I can show more information and include mySQL data or my JSON array